# How to make authenticated connection to web service with python?

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, asmx

I'm trying to authenticate the connection with the soap API on Python.
The program is simple, If authenticated is true, printing `"hello world"`, or authenticated is wrong, printing `"password or username is wrong"`
I try to authenticate with python, unfortunately, nothing appears on the console. How do I get a text to be printed target strings on the screen after making the authenticated to connection?

Python codes:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth  # or HTTPDigestAuth, or OAuth1, etc.
from requests import Session
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport
wsdl='http://localhost:49280/orhan.asmx?WSDL'
user = 'test'
password = 'test'

session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(user, password)
client = Client(wsdl,
            transport=Transport(session=session))
```

`http://localhost:49280/orhan.asmx?WSDL` is :

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" id="dark-mode-general-link"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" id="dark-mode-custom-link"/>
<style type="text/css" id="dark-mode-custom-style"/>
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<s:element name="HelloWorld">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ad" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="HelloWorldResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="HelloWorldResult" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="AuthHeader" type="tns:AuthHeader"/>
<s:complexType name="AuthHeader">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Username" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
<s:anyAttribute/>
</s:complexType>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="HelloWorldSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:HelloWorld"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="HelloWorldSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:HelloWorldResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="HelloWorldAuthHeader">
<wsdl:part name="AuthHeader" element="tns:AuthHeader"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="orhanSoap">
<wsdl:operation name="HelloWorld">
<wsdl:input message="tns:HelloWorldSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:HelloWorldSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="orhanSoap" type="tns:orhanSoap">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="HelloWorld">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
<soap:header message="tns:HelloWorldAuthHeader" part="AuthHeader" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="orhanSoap12" type="tns:orhanSoap">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="HelloWorld">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
<soap12:header message="tns:HelloWorldAuthHeader" part="AuthHeader" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="orhan">
<wsdl:port name="orhanSoap" binding="tns:orhanSoap">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:49280/orhan.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="orhanSoap12" binding="tns:orhanSoap12">
<soap12:address location="http://localhost:49280/orhan.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: you are mixing things. basic auth is done on the webserver, the username and password that you specify are part of the call but not into the soap message. if the username/pw combination fails you will get an http 40x error from the webserver. if they are correct your request will be given to the webservice. The webservice then can reply if you have specified the correct input message. from there you can get a soap response or a soap fault.